# Correlation coefficient of noise

Tags: correlation

A correlation coefficient is computed as $$r=Cov(X,Y)/(\sqrt{Var( X)}*\sqrt{Var (Y)})$$
What is the correlation coefficient of a number with itself then.
I have a noise function,assuming with a known value and variance; and I perform a correlation of noise with itself what should I get as the correlation coefficient. The noise follows a $\chi^2$ distribution.

Answer (score 2):

No matter what distribution the variable $X$ distributed as, the correlation between $X$ and itself equals 1.

$$r=Cov(X,X)/\sqrt{Var (X)}*\sqrt{Var( X)}=Var(X)/Var (X)=1.$$